# How to schedule daily job using Rufus Scheduler

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a daily job using Rufus Scheduler.
Is this a correct way doing it?

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '1d' do
  # Daily job code
end
```

Or should I create a cron job ? 
Cannot find anything in Rufus documentation.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a correct way doing it ?

Yes, it is a correct way of doing it.

> Or should I create a cron job ?

It depends on what you are building.

Doing

```
scheduler.every '1d' do
  # ...
end
```

will schedule now and then again in now + 24 * 3600 seconds and then again in now + 2 * 24 * 3600 seconds...

Doing

```
scheduler.cron '0 2 * * *' do
  # ...
end
```

will schedule every day at 2am.

Some people prefer the certainty of having some admin jobs run while the system is less busy (hence my example choice of 2am).

The rufus-scheduler documentation is explaining both and trusting you to choose the one that fits your requirements.